# Hibernate OneToOne mapping to different tables

Tags: java, database, hibernate, database-design

I need to persist a data structure that has value which is either a string, double or date.

Is there a way to do a one-to-one mapping, conditional by table?

I tried this...

```
@Table(name = "FIELD_CRITERIA")
public class FieldCriteriaEntity implements Identifiable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CRITERIA_KEY", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade =  CascadeType.ALL,optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="CRITERIA_ID")
    private StringCriteriaEntity stringCriteria;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="CRITERIA_ID")
    private NumeriCriteriaEntity numericCriteria;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="CRITERIA_ID")
    private DateCriteriaEntity dateCriteria;
}
```

However, hibernate doesn't like this:

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:

Is there a way to configure hibernate to handle this? Or should I simply re-model the FIELD_CRITERIA table to include 3 optional OneToMany relationships?

Answer (score 0):

First you may try to make DateCriteriaEntity and NumericCriteriaEntity the owners of the "one-to-one" relation, not the FieldCriteriaEntity. Move the CRITERIA_ID column to tables that correspond to NumericCriteriaEntity and DateCriteriaEntity so that the column will store FieldCriteriaEntity id as foreign key, and use @OneToMany(mappedBy="correspondent field name") in FieldCriteriaEntity instead of your variant.

Consider this article http://uaihebert.com/jpa-onetoone-unidirectional-and-bidirectional/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the better way of achieving this is to use rework your entity design slightly. Please see the following class diagram. You can create an abstract CriteriaEntity which would have the criteriaId as primary key. Please choose carefully the inheritance strategy for your sub classes. If the criteria entities are relatively simple then consider using SINGLE_TABLE or else move to TABLE_PER_CLASS.

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
```

[image: JPA entity class diagram]

You will need to rework your `FieldCriteriaEntity` to use only one mapping. Please see the following

```java
@Table(name = "FIELD_CRITERIA")
public class FieldCriteriaEntity implements Identifiable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "CRITERIA_KEY", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade =  CascadeType.ALL,optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="CRITERIA_ID")
    private CriteriaEntity criteria;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried to implement your suggestion, but i'm having issues with the abstract class.

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class FieldCriteriaEntity

Error is: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: murex.risk.compliance.excess.entities.FieldCriteriaEntity

Comment: Why do i need to specify an identifier for entity, if it's abstract.

Comment: Sorry mate forgot to mention it in my post earlier, the criteriaId needs to be declared as primary key by using @Id annotation. The foreign key in your case needs to be primary key in associated entity or table.